# Two probability questions for primes $p$ , case that $p-1$ is squarefree and $p-1$ $=$ $k^x*2^n$ with $k$ prime.

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can someone please help me figure out the theoretical probabilities given for a random prime $p$:

Probability that $p-1$ is square free (no repeated prime factors) eg. $31$, $30$ $=$ $2*3*5$.

Probability that $p-1$ $=$ $k^x*2^n$ with $k$ an odd prime. ($p-1$ has only one odd prime factor) eg. $29$, $28$ $=$ $2^2*7$, $7$ is an odd prime power. Another example is $37$, $36$ $=$ $2^2*3^2$, $9$ is an odd prime power.

(Please don't combine the probabilities, these are two separate properties.)

(FYI, when both of these properties hold, $(p-1)/2$ is called a Sophie Germain Prime.)

A quick example: $p$ $=$ $59$, $58$ $=$ $2*29$, $58$ is square free and has only one odd prime factor, $29$.

Finding the probabilities of these two properties of $p-1$, I should be able to find the probability for the following giving a prime $p$:

$p-1$ has at least one repeated prime factor and at least two (distinct) odd prime factors. eg. $127$, $126$ $=$ $2*3^2*7$.

Thanks in advance.